# installed ubuntu 20.4 from USB and stuck in GNU grub screen

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, gnu

I installed 20.4 into HP 255 notebook, removing win7. Worked fine for a few days and i learned a lot so thought i would do a re-install and start again to get everything right. Now same usb installs ok, but when I remove usb and try to use the installed Ubuntu, i always get GNU grub screen. Tried reinstalling several times, made a new usb and reinstalled, still stuck at GNU grub, also sometimes 'Common Interrupt; 1.55 No Irq handler for vector'. Please help this poor beginner, I tried all the blogs and fixes and am still stuck. Seems i'm not alone!

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Are you saying when you boot up you get the grub screen, which (by default) you should do, but when you select Ubuntu and hit *Enter*, nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

thanks. When I load ubuntu from a (purchased loaded) usb I can 'Try Ubuntu' ok. But when I load  full Ubuntu onto notebook it loads ok and says remove medium and restart. I remove, but on restarting I get black screen with 'common interrupt: 1.55 No irq handler for vector. then 'GNU grub version 2.02' across top of black screen, but no prompt or anything.
After a couple of days trying everything I could find on the web, and from the supplier, I made a new usb with download and rufus, which worked, but only if I catch the boot sequence with esc key and f9 key and make it boot from 'notebook hard drive', not any of the ubuntu choices. Any of the other boots give me 'common interrupt...etc.'
I've tried changing the boot sequence with Boot Repair, but it stays resolutly the same. So I can work around, and it's a spare pc for playing with, so not life threatening, but still.

Comment: During the installation process, did you cleanly wipe the partitions, i.e. "erase existing installations and install Ubuntu"?

Answer (score 0):

no I didn't. I just got the ubuntu install usb, stuck it in and obeyed instructions.
The usb asked if I wanted to wipe memory and install and I said yes.